# Cannot open include file: 'visa.h'

Tags: c++, windows, visa

I am working in a C++ project that uses the IVI Foundation and VISA dependencies. However, since moving over to Windows 10, I can't find where to install those onto my machine, to the point where I am wondering if they exist for windows 10. Do they exist? Where can I find them.

Comment: http://www.ivifoundation.org/shared_components/ refers to "Windows Vista" and XP as unsupported and provides .Net support libraries and don't mention C++, but probably IVI-C stands for C and C++.. This guy here tries win10: https://forums.ni.com/t5/Instrument-Control-GPIB-Serial/mingw-C-linker-error-VISA-on-Windows-10/td-p/3277906 and got response " Windows 10 is supported by NI VISA 15.5, but we don't support c++" -- but that's from National Instruments... well, what's your target device/provider? NI maybe? :)

Comment: yeah.. i have a windows 7 machine that was able to compile this.. so i think i need to be able to do the same for windows 10

Answer (score 0):

The visa.h header file (and other files that you might need to include) can be found at either of the following two paths for 64-bit Windows:
C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\include

C:\Program Files\IVI Foundation\VISA\Win64\include

For 32-bit Windows, the path will be:

C:\Program Files\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\include